# USB - filesystem is read only, what command added to a config file that runs every boot might fix this?

Tags: persistence

im using VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
and everything goes well, but after a time it restarts and says filesystem is read-only. and i have to reflash.
any solutions? PS i only have access through windows to the USB, i cannot troubleshoot directly on the machine.

i found

```
sudo mount -o rw,remount /
fsck -n -f 
killall nautilus 
killall nemo
```

I've added these in a config file. it booted with them so i guess its not that big of a risk

Comment: Check the logs before it flips *RO* for the error condition that causes the change (flipping from RW to RO).  That'll show your issue, but I'd suggest checking the health of your drive too (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)

Comment: Why those commands, they make no sense, esp. for Ubuntu 18.04.5 (`nemo` & `nautilus` are used by different file-managers intended for different desktops)